# AngularJS 2 routing on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET CORE app that uses angular2 routing. Running local routes resolve as expected. When I publish to the server (running IIS 7) the routes appear to add the folder directory where I published it. In the example below the "page url" is the page I navigate to but the "result url" is what is displayed in the browser address bar.

page url --> http://myserver/orders

result url --> http://myserver/orders/orders

Any ideas on why this is happening? Is this an IIS setting, or Angular routing issue or a .NET CORE config issue?

Here is the way I have my routes configured in angular2.

```
export const appRoutes:Routes = [
{ path: 'orders', component: OrderSearchComponent, resolve: {orders: OrderSearchResolverService}},
{ path: 'orders/new', component: CreateOrderComponent},
{ path: 'orders/:id', component: OrderDetailComponent, canActivate: [OrderRouterActivator]},
{ path: '404', component: Error404Component},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'orders', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'user', loadChildren: 'app/user/user.module#UserModule' }
]
```

On my dev box the href is set lie this:

```
<base href="/">
```

This didn't work on IIS so I've tried lots of different settings with no luck.

```
<base href=""> and <base href="/order/"> both return:

http://myserver/orders/orders
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit - to show where appRoutes is used.**

```
@NgModule({
  ...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
 ]...
```

Comment: Please show your asp.net core route configuration. Have you specified a default route as well as a "spa-fallback" route in the configuration so that only `index.html`/`index.cshtml` is being loaded?

Comment: My configuration is shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `Startup.cs` has routing configurations for a default route as well as an SPA fallback route that would serve the `index.cshtml` or equivalent for any routes rather than trying to load assets based on client side navigation.

`MapSpaFallbackRoute()` requires [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) to be installed within your application.

Configure your `Startup.cs` as follows:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
```

According to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015#configure-iis-rewrite-rules), if you are using **IIS** and not **IIS Express** you'll need to create a rewrite rule and have your base set as `<base href="/src/" />`. The `web.config` rewrite rule that's provided in the document is as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/src/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This rewrites **every** request so if you need calls to an API or similar to go through you'll need to modify the `<match url="..." />` property accordingly.

Hopefully this help!